# How to make the background color grey when a dropdownlist is disabled in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a dropdownlist when a value is selected and a button is clicked it's get disabled fine but the background-color is not grey like textboxes, I need to make the background-color grey of a dropdownlist when it is disabled in AngularJS.
JS

```
<select class="categories"  ng-model="Model.CurrentDowntime.CategoryId" ng-options="downtimeCategory.CategoryId as downtimeCategory.CategoryName for downtimeCategory in Model.DowntimeCategories" ng-disabled="Model.CurrentDowntime.EventId !== undefined" required="" >
<option value="">-------------------SELECT-----------------</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If I am right AngularJS should not switch anything else than the actual "disabled" attribute on and off? Then it is mainly up to the browser (and/or css) to handle the control's appearance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your CSS:

```
select[disabled] {
   background-color: #CCC;  //use your prefered color here
}
```

Comment: Remember that it is up to the browser to handle the background-color behavior. Safari does in example still put a gray gradient over the color.

Comment: @einord: `-webkit-appearance: none;` or an explicit override of the property *should* fix that. I say should because Safari is notorious for doing its own thing.